# Is there a syntax that chooses the true variable from the other one?

Tags: php, syntax

Let me explain this further, So I tend to do something like:

```
$foo = "";
$bar = "This is not empty"

if($foo){
  $str = $foo;
}else{
  $str = $bar;
}

magic($str)
```

I thought this is a really nasty way to approach this and there got to be some easy syntax to achieve this and i'm just being dumb.

So i tried:

```
magic($foo OR $bar)
```

Unfortunately that actually compares the two variables and returns `1` instead of the actual true variable itself.

Basically i want a syntax that checks if the first variable is empty then it'll return the second one instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, in PHP 5.3 or later, use the new version of the ternary operator:

```
$str = $foo ?: $bar;
```

If you need to support PHP 5.2 or earlier you'll have to use the slightly more verbose

```
$str = $foo ? $foo : $bar;
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Note neither these or your `if($foo){ $str = $foo; } else{ $str = $bar; }` check the value of `$bar`, your question title doesn't quite match the body.

If you have multiple items and you want to remove the empty ones you can use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php), eg:

`array_filter(array($foo, $bar, $baz));`

Comment: Note, `$foo ?: $bar` works as of PHP 5.3.  Before that, you're stuck with the long form (with another `$foo` in between the `?` and `:`).

Comment: @cHao way ahead of you (well, minutes ahead at least ;) )

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use ternary operator like this:

```
$str = $foo ? $foo : $bar;
```

It is shorthand of your code:

```
if($foo){
  $str = $foo;
}else{
  $str = $bar;
}
```

Even shorter:

```
$str = $foo ?: $bar;
```

`$str` will be equal to `$foo` or `$bar` whichever is truthy.

Answer (score 1):

Can you do this:

```
magic($foo ?  $foo : $bar);
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use ternary operators like so:

`$str = ( $foo ) ? $foo : $bar;`

That will set `$str` to `$foo` if it's not empty and `$bar` if it is. It may not be quite as simple as you are looking for, but it looks cleaner to me.